# Android: put 2 buttons in custom dialog to appear in center

Tags: java, android

I have a custom dialog.
I want to put 2 buttons one near the other horizontally, to appear in center.
How can I achieve that?

Very similiar to Yes/No message box.

I am seeking a way to do it in layout xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:width="wrap_content"
       android:height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

 ... And two buttons here
```

Comment: What worked for me in the end is instead of `android:gracity="center"` I used `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`. Editing the answer accordingly. Also there was a little typo: `android:width` and `android:height` instead of `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` respectively. Fixed this also

Comment: You are right. I was not sure and have forgotten that another parameter and I don't have Eclipse at home and couldn't check it. Sorry. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MyActivity.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

You may be looking for something similar to this. You can set the "Positive" and "Negative" button to say whatever you want and have each one do its own thing. In your case (and most cases) Yes and No would be perfect here!

Some examples of xml files can also be found by following that link as well as this one that I have used before.

[Blog about custom dialogs. (Nice Example Code)](http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/)

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted how to do it in the layout xml file.

Comment: @goryachex, no worries but the second link had some examples in it :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an xml to define the layout of the content of the Dialog anyway you want, then you use an layoutInflater to set as a view in an AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
```

Documentation source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was referring to only xml layout configuration.